# Using urllib.urllibencode values to complete search form

Tags: python, html, urllib

I've used this community a number of times, and the answers for questions I search are awesome. I have searched around for a solution to this one, but I am having problems. I think it has to do with my lack of knowledge about html code and structure. Right now I am trying to use urllib.urlencode to fill out a form on a website. Unfortunately, no matter what combinations of values I add to the dictionary, the html data returned as 'soup' is the same webpage with a list of the search options. I'm guessing that means that it is not passing the search data properly with urllib.urlencode.

An example of the webpage is:

http://www.mci.mndm.gov.on.ca/Claims/Cf_Claims/clm_cls.cfm?Div=80

which is the url I will go to, where the end DIV=80 or Div=70 etc is made in first two lines with a reference to another function 'urlData(division)'. After these lines is where the problem is happening. I've tried to include a value for each input line under the search form, but I am definitely missing something.

Code:

```
    def searchHolder(Name, division):
        url = ('http://www.mci.mndm.gov.on.ca/Claims/Cf_Claims/clm_cls.cfm'+
               '?Div='+str(urlData(division)))#creates url given above
        print url#checked its same url as the url given above for the case I am having problems with
        values = ({'HolderName': Name, 'action':'clm_clr.cfm', 'txtDiv' : 80,
                   'submit': 'Start Search'})
        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        html = urllib.urlopen(url, data)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
        soup.unicode
        print soup.text
        return soup
```

Answer (score 0):

The form "action" isn't a parameter you pass. Rather, it's the URL you need to send your request to in order to get results. Give this a try:

```
def searchHolder(Name, division):
    url = ('http://www.mci.mndm.gov.on.ca/Claims/Cf_Claims/clm_clr.cfm')
    values = ({'HolderName': Name, 'txtDiv' : 80})
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    html = urllib.urlopen(url, data)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
    soup.unicode
    print soup.text
    return soup
```